# bluetoothd issue: Not enough free handles to register service

Tags: bluetooth

I am having a problem with Bluetooth on my system.

I have bought a USB dongle and I had used it succesfully multiple times.
Today I tried again to use it and I am running into errors.
The problem is mainly using a python code which relies on pygatt.

I have bluez installed and I can see the devices from the manager, but every time I try to run my code everything crash.

Anyway, if I try sudo service bluetooth status I get:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-12-29 20:50:03 GMT; 16min ago
 Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 923 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
Tasks: 1
Memory: 2.2M
  CPU: 56ms
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
       └─923 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 29 20:50:06 jsab-u bluetoothd[923]: Error adding Link Loss service
Dec 29 20:50:06 jsa-u bluetoothd[923]: Not enough free handles to register service
Dec 29 20:50:06 jsab-u bluetoothd[923]: Not enough free handles to register service
Dec 29 20:50:06 jsab-u bluetoothd[923]: Not enough free handles to register service
Dec 29 20:50:06 jsab-u bluetoothd[923]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Dec 29 20:50:06 jsab-u bluetoothd[923]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Dec 29 20:50:06 jsab-u bluetoothd[923]: Not enough free handles to register service
Dec 29 20:50:06 jsab-u bluetoothd[923]: Not enough free handles to register service
Dec 29 20:50:06 jsab-u bluetoothd[923]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Dec 29 20:50:06 jsab-u bluetoothd[923]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

uname -a

```
Linux jsab-u 4.4.0-104-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:16:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsusb, these are my two bluetooth:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
```

In Bluetooth devices I can see my device if I scan, but cannot pair it.
If I run the code, I get a popup

"Connection to BlueZ failed

Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue.
This probably means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started."

As everything was working properly before, I guess something is wrong with my system. (the code is not developed by me, but it works for other people and it was working before).

Any suggestion to troubleshoot the problem?
I tried already following different threads, but couldn't solve.

Thanks!

Comment: I get those same errors starting up from suspend, and my bluetooth mouse still works.  Try starting the bluetooth settings, then turn off bt, then turn on BT from the settings, then check the icon and turn on BT there if greyed out -- then pairing might work.